# Shopify: Handling Form Errors On A Page With Multiple Contact Forms

Tags: forms, error-handling, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-template

Good evening Stack overflower's

On Shopify, I have one page with 3 contact forms, all with unique IDs set like so

```
{% form 'contact', id: section.settings['form-id'] %}
```

I am having issues getting the form errors because each form is displaying the form errors because the form object is being picked up by all of them.

```
{%- if form.errors -%}
```

That is present between each form tag and so is showing up in all the forms.

Is there a way to differentiate between the form errors being received like checking what form ID they have/relate to?

Any pointers to get that working?

Many thanks

Comment: P.s: I have tried using {{ form.id }} and it does not work. It is totally null, nothing is outputted when I simple try to display it in a <p> tag.

Comment: Can you share a snippet or a whole section so we can investigate? Right now in order to play with this issue I have to spend some time preparing it which I'm not into :P